# iPhone UITableView, UINavigationView and Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I'm building an app which will eventually have many tabs, tables, maps etc, however, I want to build something very simple which is turning out to be a major headache.

I'm using XCode 3.2.5 and Interface Builder to build a simple app that will show a navigation bar, and a table view.

I know there are templates but I want to build each unit so that I can later (hopefully) link it to a tab bar controller.

What I can't seem to get to happen is getting the navigation controller and table view to work together properly when built from interface builder.

I have specific reasons for building in IB over just code - some of it a learning exercise so I can help others, some because the code has to be handed off in a way that can be easily followed.

So, I've got two sets of files, mainwindow.[h/m/xib] and categories.[h/m/xib].

mainwindows.m's main code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchoptions {
  quickCats = [[categories alloc] initWithNibName:@"categories" bundle:nil];
  [window addSubView: quickCats.view];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

I've declared 'quickCats' in the mainwindow.h file as a reference to the class 'categories'.

My categories.[h/m/xib] is a stock `UIViewController` with subclassing of `UITableViewController`, I've only changed the number of sections, number of cells and cells methods to appropriately return data.

The interface declaration is literally:

```
@interface categories : UITableViewController {
}
```

When I first fire this up, it loads and displays the table so I know that works.

What I'm having problems with is getting a navigation controller to work as well.

I drop a `UINavigationController` on the objects panel and then drag the `UITableViewController` to within it so that on the IB screen it looks like i've got a nav controller and table at the same time.

Now, no matter how I wire it up, I cannot get the nav controller to fire the table view.

I have to connect the Files Owner's view to the `TableView` or my app crashes with an uncaught exception saying I didn't return a `UITableView`.

What have I missed?

I know from reading code examples that you usually add a navigation controller using `initWithRootViewController` but how do I hook all this up with IB?

Comment: I may have figured this out now, I created a code only example with a seperate class to load the NavigationController so that I could call initWithRootViewController: after initWithNibNamed:bundle: on the TableViewController class, i'll try and wire this all up in IB later on and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can't find a definitive answer to this, it seems that although IB will allow you to place a `UINavigationController` control and then add a `UITableViewController` as a child of it, you can only get `initWithNibName:bundle:` to initiate one or the other.  I've tried everything I can think of but it just won't let me wire it up so that one initialises the other when the NIB loads.

The solution to this is to create a `UIViewController` project file which subclasses `UITableViewController` and then you create a class called MyTableWithNavigation as a sublcass of `UIViewController`, expose one method called 'init' and in that you programatically create a `UINavigationController` passing `initWithRootViewController`: and then return the resulting object to the AppDelegate that called it.

This achieves the same end result but is a hybrid of IB/XCode which will have to do for now.

Basically the code in my init looks like:

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    mainTable = [[QuickCategories_iPhone_Table alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuickCategories_iPhone" bundle:nil ];
    mainNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: mainTable ];
    return mainNav;
} else {
    return nil;
}
}
```

This way, all the nice calls like self.navigationItem.title are working as well.

I'd still like to know how i'm supposed to do it the other way though.